# Assigning DependencyProperty runs slow

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

There is **Button** *button1* and **TextBox** *textBox1*. Here's *button1*'s **ClickEvent** hadler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    textBox1.Text = "some text";
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - now;
    MessageBox.Show(span.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
}
```

*span.TotalMilliseconds* is 1...2 in Debug and 0...1 in Release. But even in Release it has value of "0" only in about 2 times of 10.

Question is, why is it so slow?

I am implementing my own control similar to **DataGrid** and I have about 300 visible cells on screen. I implemented my own UI virtualization that is based on moving data "behind" the cells. So every time I scroll each cell's text gets updated. And it lasts more than 300 milliseconds.

Comment: You say you have written your own virtualizing DataGrid. Without seeing your code we have no idea why it may be so slow :) Have you tried a third party grid for speed comparison? (Telerik allows a free trial, so you could try theirs)

Comment: Yes, but actually I tried assigning text to a single **TextBox** in a Button.ClickEvent hadnler as I demonstrated in a code section. Nothing more, than **TextBox** and a **Button**. I wrote in my post, that assigning text to it takes up to 2 ms. Multiply it by 300 and get major wait.